# Deploying my website on firebase doesn't create .json file

Tags: firebase-hosting

This is the message I get when I go to view my website after completing hosting setup.

> Welcome Firebase Hosting Setup Complete You're seeing this because
> you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build
> something extraordinary!

I've done the following (per firebase support):

> Run the command, firebase use to make sure the local config is pointed
> to the correct Firebase project.
>
> I've made sure that an index.html file is present.

However, I've not been able to do this (per firebase support):

> I can't check the firebase.json file to make sure the public folder
> (or public attribute) is the same as the location of your hosting
> files.

It's because it looks like firebase init failed to create the firebase.json file as they are not in my root directory, so I'm suspecting this to be the problem.

I'm deploying from VS Code, please.

How can I get that file created? I am scheduled to launch this site tomorrow and I can't get any further responses from support (presumably it's cos of the weekend).

Many thanks for any help.